# Android WebView postMessage from iframe with pages in assets

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webview, postmessage

I have a WebView containing page A.
Page A has an iframe containing page B.
Both page A and B are in the app's assets.

Page A has a message event handler and page B calls `parent.postMessage` but I get a security problem:

> I/chromium(997): [INFO:CONSOLE(27)] "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a
>   frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null".
>   Protocols, domains, and ports must match.", source:
>   file:///android_asset/path/to/my.js

I assume the origins are null because the files are assets but is there a way to allow them to communicate in this way?

Answer (score 2):

You should enable file access from within pages. Use this setting:

```
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
```

Edit:

This setting is valid from SDK version 16.